# how to start and stop a bash script on startup and shutdown?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04

This is a script to monitor one file and notify changes

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

update_sha()
{
 sha="sha512sum /bin/myfile"
}
update_sha

previous_sha=$sha
compare()
{
  update_sha
  if [[ $sha != $previous_sha ]] ; then
  notify-send "change detected"
  build
  previous_sha=$sha

  fi
}

trap exit SIGQUIT

while true; do
compare
sleep 1
done
```

i called the script  `filecheck.sh`.  Ran  `nohup ./filecheck.sh &`  and it ran without any problems, but it only runs until you shutdown the system, so i thought ill add this to `/etc/init.d` and i updated it. But when i tried to reboot,the script kept on running and wasnt killed and i had to switch off my system. Any help about how to kill the script on shutdown would be appreciated.

Comment: Sound like you actually want `inotify`.

Comment: Can u help me with the syntax to monitor a file using `inotify` called `myfile`  for changes and `echo` if an changes occur

Comment: What did you try?  Pasting your question into Google gets me two cross-site duplicates immediately; https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes and http://serverfault.com/questions/1669/shell-command-to-monitor-changes-in-a-file-whats-it-called-again/1670

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually running `sha512sum`; you need a command substitution for that. The proper way to write this script:

```
get_sha()
{
 sha512sum /bin/myfile
}

previous_sha=$(get_sha)
compare()
{
  current_sha=$(get_sha)
  if [[ $current_sha != $previous_sha ]] ; then
    notify-send "change detected"
    build
    previous_sha=$currentsha 
  fi
}

trap exit SIGQUIT

while true; do
  compare
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I ran this too and i added it to `/etc/init.d` it still doesnt allow the system to shutdown and i think it has to do with the signals